# Php email not working error

Tags: php, apache, email, xampp

I am using xampp 1.7.4 (PHP 5.3.5) and when i send emails to my email address its working. and even i used mail server as examples its not working. below is the code.

```
<?php
    ini_set("SMTP","mail.sweetinteractive.com");
    $suc = mail("uzair@sweetinteractive.com","Learning PHP","Message is not working ","From: uzair@sweetinteractive.com");
    if($suc){
        echo "Mail sent";
    } else {
        echo "Mail sending Failed.";
    }
?>
```

And even i tried out working with our mail server. But its showing and error

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\LearnPhp\email1.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Please configure your php.ini and sendmail.ini files in xampp folder.

First : need to change the fields in php.ini (rootdrive:\xampp\php\php.ini)

---

(Note :  semicolon ';' signifies a comments in ini files)

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.sweetinteractive.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = uzair@sweetinteractive.com
```

second step : change the sendmail.ini file (rootdirectory:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini)

---

note :  remove semicolon (;) form give below fields 
and make changes in sendmail.ini file

```
smtp_server=mail.sweetinteractive.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

auth_username=uzair@sweetinteractive.com
auth_password=give your password here without any quotes
```

I believe this should gonna work. Because you are not providing any authentication parameters in previous post.

**Note : after making the changes in php.ini and sendmail.ini files, stop the apache service from Xampp control panel and run it again.**

and your php code

---

```
<?php
    ini_set("SMTP","mail.sweetinteractive.com");
    $suc = mail("uzair@sweetinteractive.com","Learning PHP","Message sending will work now","From: uzair@sweetinteractive.com");
    if($suc){
        echo "Mail sent";
    } else {
        echo "Mail sending Failed.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The code really worked. I was so messed up with code, never thought of the configuration file modifications.

Thanks for detailed help, now I'm send/receiving emails from my website.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the closing quote on the "From:" header.

Comment: Good catch, but not the problem here (probably just poor copy/paste) since that would probably produce an `E_PARSE`, and even if it didn't, the headers have not been sent at the stage that the HELO is recieved from the SMTP server...

Comment: If the From: address is malformed or missing, it might result in a malformed SMTP MAIL FROM header, too; but you are probably right, and I am not at all familiar with PHP.

Comment: True, that missing string close is not going to result in a successful email, but `HELO`/`EHLO` is the very first SMTP command, and that is what is being rejected. We haven't got near a `MAIL FROM` at the point this error is being raised.

Answer (score 0):

Your system has to send a so-called fully qualified domain name, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.1

This is most likely an anti-spam protection setting in your mailserver - it prevents "normal" client machines from sending in mail directly, a tactic that often is used by malware.

Comment: "normal"?  It only prevents misconfigured or poorly written SMTP clients from sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SMTP in your php.ini is correct, and appropriate it to your mail server.

Comment: I changed to `[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.sweetinteractive.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = uzair@sweetinteractive.com` and it didnt work out

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Change you system's host name to an FQDN (a bit extreme for this operation and may not even be possible in your setup, depending on many factors), or use [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) or similar approach that allows you to specify the name used in the HELO/EHLO.